# "nvm" command not recognized in new command line windows/tabs despite presence of "NVM_DIR" variable in both ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile

Tags: node.js, macos, unix, terminal, nvm

My colleague recently installed Node Version Manager on his Macbook using Homebrew, and ran the two commands suggested at the end of the install script:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Everything works fine in the terminal window in which the install took place, but if he opens up a new terminal window or even a new tab, he has to install NVM all over again.

My level of command-line experience is relatively low (I don't know what I don't know), so I'm not sure where to start diagnosing the problem.  Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The instructions from `brew` after installing `nvm` are:

```
Add the following to $HOME/.bashrc, $HOME/.zshrc, or your shell's equivalent configuration file:

  source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

On OS X with default settings, you actually want `$HOME/.profile` (or `~/.profile`).  Just add the line above to the end of that file.

Running that line once will set up `nvm` in that shell session.  But if you add it to your `.profile` file, it will be run at the beginning of every shell session.

Answer (score 5):

### If you don't want to edit the `.bash_profile`

You could also export the `nvm()` function to your **current shell enviroment**:

```
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

to check that is working:

```
nvm -v
```

---

### If you want to edit the `.bash_profile`

```
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Type `i` to insert, and add:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" 
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Press `wq!` to save and exit and finally restart the terminal application.

Never Give Up! ✌️